# Need help with the functions to use for this problem

Tags: finite-difference-method, implicit

Consider the following example. Suppose there is a thin rod which is insulated along its length. Suppose that the temperature is initially zero everywhere, and that the left end is suddenly heated and kept at 20 degrees. Finally we set α = 1/2. In notation, we have set the spatial interval is [−5, 5], Δx = 0.1, Δt = 0.01 and λ = 1/2. For the initial setting take u(x, 0) = 0 and for the boundary values take u(– 5, t) = 20 and u(5, t) = 0. Using (4.2.4), we solve for approximate values of u along the interval.

A) Do Exercise 1 of Section 4.2 using implicit FDM.
B) Do Exercise 1 of Section 4.2 using Crank Nicolson FDM.

Comment: **Using (4.2.4),** what is this? what is $\alpha$? it will be easier and more clear if you just scan the whole problem from the textbook with any equations given.  From which book is this problem? which section/page number? I might have the book myself.  For Mathematica solution, you can use `NDSolve` to solve the heat pde numerically and compare with that .

Comment: I noticed now you asked the same question few times before. But have not provided the additional information requested before from you. Please see comments to your previous closed questions.  I suggest you try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/  which is a forum dedicated for numerical solving and numerical methods. It might be better received there.

Comment: Its the Elements of Numerical Analysis with Mathematica by John Loustau section 4.3 questions 1 and 2.

Comment: Are you sure? I have the book in front of me, and it says for problem 1 and 2, section 4.3 the following:   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAAk3.png)   To get better help, it is better to post exact problem as given from the book. I know now the book is about using Mathematica to solve ode's and pde's.  The above is from a pdf copy I found on the net. I do not know if there is different version or not.

Comment: sorry, meant to say 4.4

Comment: OK, I see now the correct problem. Will try to provide the Mathematica code and reproduce the plot in the book, unless the question is closed then I will not be able to.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I just I just realized there is an answer which implements this already on this site. i.e. implements 4.2.4 in the book. Check [finite-difference-method-for-1d-heat-equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221121/finite-difference-method-for-1d-heat-equation) and see, code is already there.  (FDM for 1D heat pde) The $k$ in the above answer is same as $\lambda$ in the book

Comment: Thats the exact answer for this question?

Comment: It is, but you need to modify the code and change `delT` and `h` there to the value you are given for your problem. `h` is same as $\Delta x$. And also change the BC to whatever you have. The code as you see implements Forward Euler which is what problem 1 is asking. Try it and see.

Comment: Thank you, and will do

Answer (score 1):

This is modification of the answer in [Finite difference method for 1D heat equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221121/finite-difference-method-for-1d-heat-equation)  to make it fit your problem.

To solve problem 1 at page 83  of book

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Compare to the book plot

[image]

Here is the code

```
makeA[n_, λ_] := 
 Module[{A, i, j}, A = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, n}];
  Do[Do[A[[i, j]] = 
     If[i == j, 1 - 2 λ, 
      If[i == j + 1 || i == j - 1, λ, 0]], {j, 1, n}], {i, 1, 
    n}];
  A[[1, 1]] = 1;
  A[[1, 2]] = 0;
  A[[-1, -1]] = 1;
  A[[-1, -2]] = 0;
  A]

makeInitialU[nPoints_, ic_, leftBC_, rightBC_] := Module[{u, j},
  u = Table[0, {j, nPoints}];
  Do[u[[j]] = If[j == 1, leftBC, If[j == nPoints, rightBC, ic]],
   {j, 1, nPoints}
   ];
  u]

updateU[currentU_, leftBC_, rightBC_, A_] := Module[{u},
  u = A . currentU;
  u[[1]] = leftBC;(*set to BC condition*)
  u[[-1]] = rightBC;(*set to BC condition*)
  u]

ic = 0;
leftBC = 20;
rightBC = 0;
α = 1/2;
delT = 0.01;
delX = 0.1;
λ = (α delT )/delX;
xGrid = Range[-5, 5, delX];
n = Length[xGrid];
(A = makeA[n, λ]) // MatrixForm;
```

And the Manipulate code is

```
Manipulate[
 If[currentTime == 0,
  currentU = makeInitialU[n, ic, leftBC, rightBC],
  currentU = updateU[currentU, leftBC, rightBC, A]
  ];
 Grid[{{Row[{"time = ", currentTime}]},
   {ListPlot[currentU, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 20}}, 
     ImageSize -> 300, DataRange -> {-5, 5}]}
   }],
 
 {{currentTime, 0, "time?"}, 0, 10, delT, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{currentU, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {currentTime}
 ]
```

Problem 2 you just need to modify $\alpha$ which will change $\lambda$ and you should see from the simulation it becomes not stable when $\lambda>0.5$